# sql query search multiple words in different columns

Tags: sql, performance, indexing

I have shopping cart which has obviously some products data. user can search anything.

like iphone 3g mobile

obviously I have few columns to find these two words and there would be so many records which would have all of these words and some would have either 1 of them.

lets just say I have columns to find, columns names are `Title` `Description`

its very easy for me to break down these words and search as `title like '%iphone%' or title like '%mobile%' or....`

my concerns are:

What is best way to do this (Efficient)

I want records which has all these 3 keywords in title or description should come first then those which would have 2 of them and so on

Comment: Use the full text capabilities of your DBMS

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MySQL, I would suggest the fulltext search option.
From the [official example](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-natural-language.html):

```
SELECT * FROM items
    WHERE MATCH (title,description)
    AGAINST ('mobile' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

You should also create a relevant fulltext index:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX idx ON items(title,description)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind going dynamic

```
Declare @SearchFor  varchar(max) ='Daily,Production,default'  -- any comma delim string
Declare @SearchFrom varchar(150) ='OD'                        -- table or even a join statemtn
Declare @SearchExpr varchar(150) ='[OD-Title]'                -- Any field or even expression
Declare @ReturnCols varchar(150) ='[OD-Nr],[OD-Title]'        -- Any field(s) even with alias 

Set @SearchFor = 'Sign(CharIndex('''+Replace(Replace(Replace(@SearchFor,' , ',','),', ',''),',',''','+@SearchExpr+'))+Sign(CharIndex(''')+''','+@SearchExpr+'))'
Declare @SQL nvarchar(Max) = 'Select * from (Select Distinct'+@ReturnCols+',Hits='+@SearchFor+' From '+@SearchFrom + ') A Where Hits>0 Order by Hits Desc' 

Exec(@SQL)
```

Returns

```
OD-Nr   OD-Title                    Hits
3       Daily Production Summary    2        <<< Notice 2 of 3 hits
6       Default Settings            1
```

Comment: Had it in my head you were SQL Server.

Comment: dynamic sql... i am very much concerned about performance as i have 100,000s of products to search in... how can we do without dynamic and most efficient way

Comment: how would it search in multiple columns?

Comment: @MuhammadAdnan Define them in SearchExpr i.e. FieldA+FieldB